# Hard coded string manipulation vs Xelement when creating XML element

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq

In c# if I have to create a new XElement I can use the following two methods.

Method 1

```
string m = "<address>";
       m += "<addressline1>" + address.Addressline1 + "</addressline1>";
       m += "<addressline2>" + address.Addressline2 + "</addressline2>";
       m += "<city>" + address.Addressline1 + "</city>";
       m += "<postcode>" + address.Addressline1 + "</postcode>";
       m += "</address>";
```

Method 2

```
XElement a = new XElement("address",
                     new XElement("addressline1", address.Addressline1),
                     new XElement("addressline2", address.Addressline2),
                     new XElement("city", address.City),
                     new XElement("postcode", address.postcode)
                                  );
```

Which method is more preferable if my end goal is just to obtain a custom object as XML string?

Comment: XElement. Not only will it auto XML-encode stuff for you, it will also make it far easier to handle.

Comment: -1 for opinion based question, even though choice 2 is obviously better.

Comment: @Brad: Hmmm. I wouldn't call this a matter of opinion. Using string manipulation is clearly wrong.

Comment: Thanks Brad I am a newbie and this question may someday help another newbie in learning.

Comment: At least one of the two methods (Method 1) does not create a new XElement.

Comment: This is not an opinion based question. It can be answered in a precise and non ambiguous way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly advise to use the second method. If your values come from the variables of course. If your xml is defined and is not going to change, store it on the file system in form of xml file and load them on demand.

There are a few reasons why you should not do as in first example

- The data can contain `<` or `>` characters that can cause problems, the second way handles it automatically
- Code readability drops significantly in the first case
- Hard code is a serious antipattern
- The second approach gives you solid tools for further manipulation with the object as an XML document

Answer (score 6):

Don't ever use string manipulation to build XML. Use an XML API such as `XElement` instead. It knows all of the rules of XML, and string concatenation does not.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is better, because XElement will escape all the values for you.